# How to extract specified lines from text file with a couple of lines before?

Tags: logging, text

I have a collection of large server log files with recorded errors that interest me, looking like this:

```
2013-08-14 07:49:00,490 [ajp-8009-5] ERROR com.el.filter.SiteFilter - Caught Top-Level Exception - request=http://www.site2.com/something/home.dept?page=error&buy=123&switchcurrency=EUR
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.el.servlet.Helper.checkJData(Helper.java:1205)
    at com.el.servlet.ElServlet.doPost(ElServlet.java:113)
```

(...)

```
2013-08-14 08:18:37,984 [ajp-8009-3] ERROR com.el.filter.SiteFilter - Caught Top-Level Exception - request=http://www.site1.com/productId=123456.html
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.el.servlet.Helper.checkJData(Helper.java:1205)
    at com.el.servlet.ElServlet.doPost(ElServlet.java:113)
```

Like I mentioned those are pretty large files and there's a lot of NullpointerExceptions in them, caused by all kinds of stuff.

I'm interested in **extracting from all those files the urls that caused NPE at checkJData method**. I know I can grep all the lines 'at com.el.servlet.Helper.checkJData(Helper.java:1205)', but how to get the two lines before that?

Is there a tool to do that in Windows? If not bash script would also be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash scripting:

```
egrep -B1 "java.lang.NullPointerException" * | grep "request=" | cut -d"=" -f2-
```

Instead of * put path to those log files.

Comment: What I needed was actually egrep -B2 "checkJData" * | grep "request=" | cut -d"=" -f2-   but you got me there, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Windows solution: This uses a helper batch file called findrepl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

```
findrepl "at com.el.servlet.Helper.checkJData\(Helper.java:1205\)" /o:-2:+0 <file.log
```